# Slowly painting a line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I want this to slowly create a line that paints from 10,0 to 10,600. The line won't even paint at all, the only reason why I think it isn't working is my format and placing of different components are a little off? Why?

```
public class Moving extends JPanel {
    int counter;
    Timer time;
    public void setUp() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                counter++;
                repaint();

            }
        };
        time = new Timer(100, action);
        time.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(10, counter, 20, 20);
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Moving game = new Moving();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame"); 
        frame.setSize(320, 340);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.add(game);
        game.setUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to change the question, particular after an answer has being added, it might be nice append the changes as it makes any existing questions some what irrelevant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not added `Moving` to the frame you create...

**Updated**

I've updated the code slightly to demonstrate the point, adding `Moving` to a frame.  I've also included the [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) requirements

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Moving extends JPanel {

    int counter;
    Timer time;

    public Moving() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                counter++;
                repaint();

            }
        };
        time = new Timer(100, action);
    }

    public void start() {
        time.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(10, counter, 20, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Moving moving = new Moving();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(moving);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                moving.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And `counter` isn't `volatile` anyway.

Comment: @chrylis In this context, I don't think it needs to be, it's only be accessed from a single thread context...

Comment: Ahh, their we go! What does volatile mean?

Comment: Yes thank you!! But how would you get it to not get rid of the old rectangle, I would like the rectangle to stay each time it moves so it creates a line at the end?

Comment: `volatile` basically ensures a certain level atomic action, where a value can not be read until it has finished being written, see [Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) for more details.  In this context, it is irrelevant, as you only ever read and write the variable from the same thread context (the EDT)

Comment: @ImGone98 Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it solved the problem.

Comment: @Radiodef I will, don't worry. Yea I understand can be annoying sometimes, I think patience is a virtue though(;

Comment: Lots of people don't so I feel the need to drop by and remind them. ; )

Comment: No, `counter++` is being called from the `Timer`'s task, which is by definition in its own thread. Then he's also calling `repaint` from that thread.

Comment: @chrylis No, it's being called from the `ActionListener` registered to a `javax.swing.Timer` which guarantees calls to `actionPeformed` are executed from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  There is and never was any `TimerTask`

Comment: Crap, missed the import. Sorry.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think the OP had imports, I just picked it out of the constructor. You have a valid point, just out of context ;)